# proplem with jquery tabs while navigating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

after i finished tabs on my website i found that when i navigate from the first tab to the next tab it works well but if i try to navigate from first tab to last one or the third one it will crash and not work

this is the full code jquery, Css and html code

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
            var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');
     
            // Show/Hide Tabs
    jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).siblings().slideUp(400);
    jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).delay(400).slideDown(400);

            // Change/remove current tab to active
            jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
     
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

```css
/*********************************************************************************/
/* Tabs                                                                          */
/*********************************************************************************/

.tabs {
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
}
 
    /*----- Tab Links -----*/
    /* Clearfix */
    .tab-links:after {
        display:block;
        clear:both;
        content:'';
    }
 
    .tab-links li {
        margin:0px 5px;
        float:left;
        list-style:none;
    }
 
        .tab-links a {
            padding:9px 15px;
            display:inline-block;
            border-radius:3px 3px 0px 0px;
            background:#65A69E;
            font-size:16px;
            font-weight:600;
            color:#4c4c4c;
            transition:all linear 0.15s;
        }
 
        .tab-links a:hover {
            background:#81B6AF;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
 
    li.active a, li.active a:hover {
        background:#56928B;
        color:#4c4c4c;
    }
 
    /*----- Content of Tabs -----*/
    .tab-content {
        padding:15px;
        border-radius:3px;
        box-shadow:-1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
        background:#fff;
    }
 
        .tab {
            display:none;
        }
 
        .tab.active {
            display:block;
        }
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tab-links">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">DOMUS  LIFT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">MRL LIFT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">OIL LIFT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4">ESCALATORS</a></li>
        </ul>
 
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
            <h3>Efficiency and flexibility</h3>
            <p> problems on private , public and commercial buildings .</p>
            <p>onsumptions and low investment costs , all of which making DOMUS LIFT the best solution for any project.</p>
           
        </div>
 
        <div id="tab2" class="tab">
            <h3>MRl LIFT</h3>
            <p>MRl LIFT able both on new building and on the existing ones in need of recovery and increase of value</p>
                        
        <div id="tab3" class="tab">
            <h3>OLEO-LIFT</h3>
            <p>The OLEO-LIFT performance are suitable for </p>
            
              </div>
         
          <div id="tab4" class="tab">
            <h3>ESCALATORS</h3>
            <p>s production , both for the lift companies and for the robotized mobility .asiness on their after sale service
</p>

           
        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

please help

Comment: Its **too-broad to understand**.

Comment: pls copy code to fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are facing is because you have not closed div which contains

#### MRl LIFT

Correct code -

```
    <div id="tab2" class="tab">
        <h3>MRl LIFT</h3>
        <p>MRl LIFT able both on new building and on the existing ones in need of recovery and increase of value</p>
    </div>
```

Link to jsfiddle with corrected code -

http://jsfiddle.net/Ashish_developer/7acahwnp/4/

Answer (score 0):

[JQuery UI tabs](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#entry-examples) are your friend here.

Include the JQuery UI script in your html, after JQuery:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Then change your JavaScript to the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $( "div.tabs" ).tabs();
});
```

There are a host of options that you can use. See the documentation for more info. For Styling advice, check out the [examples](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/).